# SQL Server Adventureworks SalesOrderDetail table primary key

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to ask about the actual reason using the field `SalesOrderId` as part of the primary key. I think that this should be only a foreign key to the table `SalesOrderHeader`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear as you haven't shared your schema and other details, But i guess this link would be helpful to you http://database-programmer.blogspot.in/2008/01/database-skills-sane-approach-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok a little about indexes There are mutiple types. There is a clustered index which determines the physical order the data has on the disk, without this the table is technically known as a heap. Access of an large volume of data is inefficient. The data is random. Any non clustered index (and statistics about data distribution) will refer to the custered index to access data. When an index is built the query optimiser will use indexed columns from the left in order to find data. So when there is an index col1, col2, col3 if I am joining, searching or whatever on col1, the index will be used. If Im filtering on col1,col2 the same index will be used. There is little or no penalty for this. If my query references col1, col2, col3 ONLY (including where and returned columns etc) the the information to be returned can be acertained by ONLY reading the index, the table its self does not need to be accessed. This is known as a covering index. So this is very quick. In general, tables should be narrow, indexes wide. To find out more I recommend http://www.insidesqlserver.com/thebooks.html Kalen Delany: she knows the SQL dev team personally and writes very clearly. The basic principles are still true from SQL7 through to SQL2012 - although sparce indexes, spatial data types, BI and a lot of other goodies have been added.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info but the question remains. I dont see the reason for a compound primary key in the SalesOrderDetail table. The field SalesOrderDetailId is an identity column.. While SalesOrderDetailID could be a primary key by it self, I think the AdventureWorks design team chose to make it a composite key on SalesOrderID and SalesOrderDetailID because it is also the clustered key and they anticipate the insertion to be in ascending order by SalesOrderID and it doesn't make it necessary to have second index on SalesOrderID.

Comment: Ok, so you clearly have a good idea of what is going on, so appologies for a basic ansere. I think you have actually answered your own question. If SalesOrderDetail became very large, it would help the retrival time if the details for a single order were physically located together on disk. Whist this may occur natuarlly, it would give the query optimiser extra information that "yes these records are together and therfore I'll get them all in a single read" as opposed to here is some master detail arrangement where the details can be scattered over an entire table.

Comment: Yes I know that this is unlikely if its an order and orderdetails, but the SQL optimiser does not have this worldly context (unless you tell it by the compound clustered index). I think this is what they were getting at, and you are right, for master detail it would in general not be a good idea as it would certainly hit insert performance especially if you did not have fill space on the table. Just in case fillfactor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx So actually I think this is a very good question, once we go to the bottom of it.

Comment: Actually just came across this post which is relevant to the discussion, be sure to read the comments: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11379/sql-server-t-sql-best-practice-composite-primary-keys-performance-and-accuracy-impact.aspx